# BASH: difference between "export k=1" vs. "k=1"

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am going to write an script and It looks there is no difference between:

```
export k=1
```

and

```
k=1
```

Am I right?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Every process, even on Windows, has a block of memory known as the *environment block*, this contains *environment variables*.  When a new process is created, by default, the environment block of the parent process is copied to the child, so environment variables are a simple way of passing  text data to a child process.

The `export` command creates an environment variable, or converts an ordinary local variable into an environment variable.  In the C-shell, one of its few redeeming features is that it uses a different syntax for environment variables (`setenv`) to local variables (`set`).  Bourne shell derivatives, like Bash and Korn shell, hide all that.

Currently, only simple values can be passed, so items like arrays are not supported (it just exports the first element).  Variable attributes, set using `define`, are also not exported unless the child process is a shell of the same type, i.e. another instance of bash.  This also applies to exported functions, although it is possible to sometimes hack this between shells of different types (using `eval`).

In Bash (and others) there is a shell setting called `allexport` which means all variables are environment variables - probably a bad idea to se generally.  You can supply a different environemnt block from languages like C using `execve`, but from the shell you need a program like `env`, see `man env` for details.

Answer (score 42):

`export` makes the variable available to subprocesses.

That is, if you spawn a new process from your script, the variable `k` won't be available to that subprocess unless you `export` it. Note that if you change this variable in the subprocess that change *won't* be visible in the parent process.

See section 3.2.3 of [this doc](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_02.html) for more detail.

Answer (score 24):

I've created a simple script to show the difference:

```
$ cat script.sh 
echo $answer
```

Let's test without `export`

```
$ answer=42
$ ./script.sh 

$ . script.sh 
42
```

The value is known only if using the *same* process to execute the script (that is, the same `bash` instance, using `source` / `.`)

Now, using `export`:

```
$ export answer=42
$ ./script.sh 
42
$ . script.sh 
42
```

The value is known to the subprocess.

Thus, if you want the value of a variable to be known by subprocesses then you should use `export`.

Comment: thanks for simple examples! I had issues with this difference, because when the value is already exported (`export answer=42`) and you change it without export (e.g. `answer=30`), the change is visible to the subprocess (i.e. getting _30_ with `./script.sh`), that's what confused me. So when you're working with already existing exported values without export, you can be surprised one day! Better to use export whenever you need the visibility across subprocesses than rely on "it works at the moment".