# Accessing user defined environment variables in C program in linux?

Tags: c, linux, bash, extern

I am new in linux.I have problem in accessing my defined environment varibales in C program.

I have defined one variable in linux command terminal as follows:

```
 $   ExampleVar="Hi"
```

And in C program I am trying to access it using

```
getenv("ExampleVar")
```

But it is null every time. When I try to access other environment variables like USER, getenv gives correct results. I have also tried `extern` collection of `unistd.h`

It is not showing ExampleVar too.

Please help me.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561654/bash-difference-between-export-k-1-vs-k-1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends upon your shell. If you use `bash` -see [bash(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html) for more- type

```
 export EXAMPLEVAR="Hi"
```

in the shell (e.g. in the terminal before running your program), then use `getenv("EXAMPLEVAR")` in your C program. See [getenv(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getenv.3.html)

<sup>If you don't [`export`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#index-export) a bash variable `foo`, you still can use `$foo` in your bash commands, but `getenv("foo")` would fail and return NULL from inside compiled C programs.</sup>

Conventionally, environment variables have full capital names. See [environ(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html)

See also [env(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/env.1.html) command.

Comment: With bash you can also prefix the variable on the command line `EXAMPLEVAR=Hi ./myprog`